# openui5 1.38 attach event scrollbar

Tags: scrollbar, sapui5

from the last version update (from openui5 1.36.12 to openui5 1.38.4) the following code is not working anymore:

```
var myTable = new sap.ui.table.Table();
myTable ._oVSb.attachScroll(function() { 
   colorTheTableRows();
})
```

I'm using the "attachScroll" event in order to color the table rows with a specific logic.
Since last openui5 version update I get this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachScroll' of undefined
```

I've tried to debug the problem and it seems that the object _oVSb has be removed from sap.ui.table.Table.

My final goal is to paint the rows with different colors based on the content ... is there any other way to reach this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i want this event some how came to this thread. i tried @Dopedev solution it was not working then i changed bit in that as below

```
              $("#<tablid>-vsb").scroll(function() { 
                 console.log("Table is scrolled")
              });
```

instead of getting the tbody get the ***table-id*-vsb** and attach the scroll function

Comment: YES! It works! But I put your solution inside an "setTimeout" function because when javascript execute this code the table is not yet showed.. so I have to wait a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can still get scroll event for your table using [.scroll()](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) of jQuery.

```
onAfterRendering: function(){
    //Register handler for scroll event

    $("tbody").scroll(function(){
        // your stuff
    });

}
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/dohoxu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: It seems not a working solution:

I made an examble on JS BIN with my original code:
https://jsbin.com/piwohoyuro/1/edit?html,output
If you try to replace the link library from 1.36.12 to 1.38.4 the _oVSb object it seems not existing anymore.

In the following example you will find your code:
https://jsbin.com/lizexucapa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Please check demo I have added scroll event for `tbody` because we scroll items inside `tbody` for `Table`; further, you can modify selector `$("tbody")` to make it uniquely identified.

Comment: I don't see your corrections: I've done a new JSBIN using tbody selector but still it doesn't work. https://jsbin.com/bosifudivi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Yes it's working! please check once, I have again modified link. Records which has *Italy* are red, and that's what you wanted, right?

Comment: Sorry... maybe I'm wrong.. but "Italy" is red only at the begining... if you scroll is not red anymore but the sapui5 maintain red always the same displayed rows. I prepare some image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ethf35vd69dwfu1/2016-07-18_11h51_04.png?dl=1  https://www.dropbox.com/s/sw6dgn5vy2lc73y/2016-07-18_11h51_07.png?dl=1https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfzr04jyomtwe4k/2016-07-18_11h51_11.png?dl=1 https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqxbm2srzedk4pc/2016-07-18_11h51_18.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I know that one of the earlier posts was already marked as the 'right' answer, but it did not work for me, so I thought I would post my working solution, as it might be helpful to others. The following code will work to effectively 'attach' to the vertical scroll event of a table in 1.38:

```
    onAfterRendering: function() {
        if (this.firstTime) { //You only want to override this once
            var oTable = this.getView().byId("<YOUR_ID_HERE>");
            //Get a reference to whatever your custom handler is
            var oHandler = this.handleScroll;

            //Store a reference to the default handler method
            var oVScroll = oTable.onvscroll;
            oTable.origVScrollHandler = oVScroll;

            oTable.onvscroll = function(i) {
                //Call the 'default' UI5 handler
                oTable.origVScrollHandler(i);

                //Call your handler function, or whatever else you want to do
                oHandler();
            };

            this.firstTime = false;
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

`var myTable = new sap.ui.table.Table("myTable");`

After rendering:

`sap.ui.getCore().byId("myTable-vsb").attachScroll(function() { 
   colorTheTableRows();
})`